# How to link folder / GitHub repository to Heroku?

Tags: github, heroku, discord.js

I am hosting a Discord bot on Heroku so it stay live 24/7. I have the code local on my computer and update the code by running the below code. My only question is how can I access the code on another computer to work away from home.

```
git add .
git commit -am "making it better"
git push Heroku master
```

Comment: I wasn't clear earlier that I am making a discord bot. I have the code file on my laptop and am wondering how I can make it so when I update the heroku code directly from my computer using it's CLI it will also update the git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to "make the folder a GitHub link". Heroku builds your application and its runtime into a [slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) and this slug is what runs on your dynos. There is no way to update the code you're running without building a new slug.

However, you *can* [deploy directly from GitHub](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration), either manually or automatically when new commits are added to a branch. I strongly recommend having a good test suite in either case, but this is especially important if you want to do automatic deployments.

Comment: So when i make an edit to the repo on GitHub it will update on heroku?

Comment: If you enable automatic deploys then yes, when you push new commits to whatever branch you set up for automatic deployment (or merge a pull request or similar), [a new build will be triggered on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys). I encourage you to read the documentation. The build can take some time, just like a regular build. You can view the output of the build through the Heroku dashboard. Again, I _strongly_ recommend having a decent test suite, configuring CI on GitHub, and only deploying to Heroku once CI passes.